# Django - How to Populate Select Data Dynamically in Admin Panel

Tags: django, dynamic, admin, panel

I want to add functionality to my application that is similar to what is shown below,

Teachers - Table (Teacher | Institute):
1. Teacher 1 | ABC School
2. Teacher 2 | XYZ School

Department Table (Department | Institute):
1. Computers | ABC School
2. History | XYZ School

When I want to add a student to the system, I should be able to add him to a department in a particular school. If I use ForeignKey() then all the departments and schools are listed in drop-downs. This could lead to incorrect insertion of records. I want to dynamically load the departments after and only after the school has been selected in the admin panel. I tried many things but couldn't get it to work. I am fairly new to Django and would appreciate any help that I can get in this regard.

Comment: You might want to consider a custom interface where you use javascript to hide and show based on actions instead of the admin interface.

Comment: Of the "many things" you tried could you post what you consider the most promising thing and explain why it didn't work?

Comment: @ci_ The most promising thing I tried was to use "limit_choices_to" as an argument to the ForeignKey() call in one of the scenarios where I were to view only those Teachers who hold an administrative position. It worked well in the use case I was targeting but was not a generic solution to this problem. Apart from that I developed a custom page for this purpose which is not part of the admin panel. It works but I want to do it in the admin panel only.

Comment: @C.B. The data to be considered is held in a MySQL database and the relation on which the decision will be made requires information which is not shown in the dropdown (The dropdown shows Names while the relation involves institute IDs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very useful library called django_smart_selects that allowed me to do exactly what I wanted.

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects